# How to calculate the sum of several total amounts?

Tags: javascript, scope, angular7, calculation

I have an array of objects in which I am creating properties that I need to display in the html. This is the structure of one of the objects in the array

```
 {
    "functional_id": "201911291131250012400000SD4AYAA1",
    "transactions": [
      {
        "quantity": 2,
        "price": 140,
        "item": {
          "name": "Carton de 10 coffrets",
          "description": "+ 2 recharges d'argile offertes",
          "product": {
            "name": "Coffret empreinte rouge"
          }
        },
        "amount": 280
      },
      {
        "quantity": 2,
        "price": 17,
        "item": {
          "name": "1 lanterne d'accueil + 1 accroche porte",
          "product": {
            "name": "Lanterne d'accueil",
            "description": "Lors d'une euthanasie, cette affichette verticale auto-éclairée par bougie LED, est disposée à l’accueil. Elle montre l’importance de ce moment pour votre clinique. <br /> Les accroches porte déposés sur les poignées des salles de consultation invitent au calme."
          }
        },
        "amount": 34
      },
      {
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "item": {
          "name": "Petit modèle",
          "description": "Par 25",
          "product": {
            "name": "Sacs blancs",
            "description": "Pour les crémations Plurielles"
          }
        },
        "amount": 0
      },
      {
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "item": {
          "name": "Moyen modèle",
          "description": "Par 20",
          "product": {
            "name": "Sacs blancs",
            "description": "Pour les crémations Plurielles"
          }
        },
        "amount": 0
      },
      {
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "item": {
          "name": "Grand modèle",
          "description": "Par 10",
          "product": {
            "name": "Sacs blancs",
            "description": "Pour les crémations Plurielles"
          }
        },
        "amount": 0
      },
      {
        "quantity": 2,
        "price": 0,
        "item": {
          "product": {
            "name": "Carnet de conventions"
          }
        },
        "amount": 0
      }
    ],
    "date": "29/11/2019",
    "order_number": "113125"
  }
```

at this point I create a property 'amount' for each 'transaction' to calculate the total amount of the purchase of each product.

```
    public inicializeData() {

        this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(true);
        this.cartsSubscription = this.cartsService.getCarts().subscribe(carts => {
            this.orders = carts;
            this.orders.forEach(cart => {
                const day = cart.functional_id.substring(6, 8);
                const month = cart.functional_id.substring(4, 6);
                const year = cart.functional_id.substring(0, 4);
                cart.date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
                cart.order_number = cart.functional_id.substring(8, 14);
                cart.transactions.forEach(item => {
                    item.amount = item.quantity * item.price;
                });
            });
            this.load = true;
            this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(false);
        });
    }
```

The problem is that I would also need a total amount for all the transactions but I cannot calculate this total.
First I declare a class variable with a value of 0 and at the point where I calculate the 'item.amount' I add them all up.

```
public amount = 0;

 public inicializeData() {

        this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(true);
        this.cartsSubscription = this.cartsService.getCarts().subscribe(carts => {
            this.orders = carts;
            this.orders.forEach(cart => {
                const day = cart.functional_id.substring(6, 8);
                const month = cart.functional_id.substring(4, 6);
                const year = cart.functional_id.substring(0, 4);
                cart.date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
                cart.order_number = cart.functional_id.substring(8, 14);
                cart.transactions.forEach(item => {
                    item.amount = item.quantity * item.price;
                    this.amount += item.amount;
                });
            });
            this.load = true;
            this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(false);
        });
    }
```

and I see that what I get is the total of all the transactions. Which is not desired.

I understand it's a scope problem. But I also tried to declare the variable inside the last forEach, but it didn't work either.

```
    public inicializeData() {

        this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(true);
        this.cartsSubscription = this.cartsService.getCarts().subscribe(carts => {
            this.orders = carts;
            this.orders.forEach(cart => {
                const day = cart.functional_id.substring(6, 8);
                const month = cart.functional_id.substring(4, 6);
                const year = cart.functional_id.substring(0, 4);
                cart.date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
                cart.order_number = cart.functional_id.substring(8, 14);
                cart.transactions.forEach(item => {
                    item.amount = item.quantity * item.price;
                    let overallAmount = 0;
                    overallAmount += item.amount;
                });
            });
            this.load = true;
            this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(false);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.orders));
        });
    }
```

What I would need is that in the example object I could create a property that was the sum of all the item.amount (in this case it would be overallAmount = 314).

Someone to make me see my mistake. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line  `this.amount += item.amount;` 
try and do

```
const cal = item.quantity * item.price;
            item.amount=cal
            this.amount += cal;
```

or

```
var amount=[]
const cal = item.quantity * item.price;
                item.amount=cal
                var.push(cal)
amount=amount.reduce((a,b)=>{return a+b})
```

If you prefer to add a property transaction amount to your object you can use this

```
t=0
x= cart.transactions.filter(x=>cart['transac-amount']=t+=x.amount)
console.log(cart)
```

it will add a transaction amount to your object

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help and your time.
In the first of your solutions gives me the total amount of the sum of all 'item.amount', I tried to initialize with value 0 the global variable in each iteration and gives me in all the same value (140) that corresponds to the last of the operations

Comment: in the second solution it gives me a value of 0 for all the interactions. and in the third one it gives again the global value of the sum of all the values and adding the initialization to 0 of accumulator it gives me again the last result for all the values that I look for

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd like to thank everyone who helped. I found the solution thanks to the approaches you gave me. I ended up creating a property in the object 'cart' in which I enter the value of the sum of the amount of each of the items. 
My main mistake was that I did all the operations in the same scope or I tried to accumulate it in a class variable, which returned the total of all the items.
Here I leave you my solution that works perfectly.
Thanks again for the help

```
    public inicializeData() {

        this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(true);
        this.cartsSubscription = this.cartsService.getCarts().subscribe(carts => {
            this.orders = carts;
            this.orders.forEach(cart => {
                const day = cart.functional_id.substring(6, 8);
                const month = cart.functional_id.substring(4, 6);
                const year = cart.functional_id.substring(0, 4);
                cart.date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
                cart.order_number = cart.functional_id.substring(8, 14);
                const cash = [];
                cart.overallAmount = 0;
                cart.transactions.forEach(item => {
                    item.amount = item.quantity * item.price;
                    cash.push(item.amount);
                    cart.overallAmount = cash.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
                });
            });
            this.load = true;
            this.loaderService.eLoader.emit(false);
        });
    }
```

Comment: can elaborate what is the difference between your solution and the second solution i provided ? i haven't understand why my third solution didn't work for you since it returns 314 like you have mentioned in the question which is the total amount ? i am curious to know

Comment: @Sven.hig I suppose it's a question of inexperience on my part programming, but your second solution, used as it stands, doesn't work, one because of the problem of the empty array declaration in the initial scope, and secondly the application of your reduce without the value 0 apart from the sum of values doesn't return the desired value for each of the transactions either. 
In my response I thank you for your ideas, because they have led me to see my initial error and correct it little by little.

Comment: I am genuinley asking because i want to learn from my mistakes as well ,my second solution didn't return the desired result simply because of a 'typo'  in this line                 `var.push(cal)` misspelled it should be `amount.push` as i declared amount as an emty array to be used already, in addition the 0 you added in your reduce doesn't make any difference if you were to delete it you will still get the same results